Windows Server's local TCP port range is silently blocked by something
I am dealing with a Windows Server 2022 Standard device (Build 20348) that displays very strange behaviour related to local TCP ports.
There is a range of ports inside the usual dynamic range (the local ports used for outgoing connections), roughly 2000 ports wide, that cannot be used. For example, the default dynamic port range is 49152 to 65535. But then there's a gap around e.g. 61164 to 63139 that causes programs to display network socket related error messages, usually some form of Windows socket error 10013.
This locked range is not fixed, it seems to shift around by thousands with restarts of the server. This circumvented my initial workaround of decreasing Windows' dynamic port range to avoid the problematic range.
The usual observations/explanations that I could find after extensive searching sadly do not apply:

It is a physical server, not virtualized, not running any virtualization
The default Windows firewall (no other firewall or network security software is running) does not have any rules for these ports, and this wouldn't explain the shifting port range anyway, plus the problem persisted with it temporarily turned off
The most common culprit is apparently an excluded tcp port range, however the configured excluded ports are narrow program-specific exclusions and do not match the affected range
The available diagnostic tools like Resource Monitor and Netstat show no registered TCP listening ports in that range, let alone connections. This makes it seemingly impossible to find any relevant process that might be reserving the ports.
This also happens with connections explicitly made to localhost, so external network issues shouldn't provide an explanation either

To summarize, there's a port range that creates binding errors like they're locked by something, but the range does not show up in any network related settings/diagnostics and apparently changes position on reboot.
I'm not in a position to do "big" changes like setting the system up again from scratch, so I hope anyone here has an idea on how to analyze the culprit of this behaviour.

Does the same error occur when you use PowerShell to create a TCP listener on an affected port? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129162/175990

This answer -- https://superuser.com/a/1840570/766217 -- has some Python code that will check all ports. Maybe it can help narrow things down.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/default-dynamic-port-range-tcpip-chang might helpful in here due it is not silently blocked but good documented by Microsoft ;)
